# Sightly/HTL listChildren on different than current path

Tags: sling, sightly

In Apache Sling, I can do something like this with HTL/sightly:

```
<div data-sly-list="${resource.listChildren}">
        <p>title: ${item.title}</p>
</div>
```

Variable resource points to the current path of, say, /a/b/c. How can I get a resource at /x/y/z and list its children? That's through the resolver global variable but I am unclear about the syntax to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-sly-use` to grab a `Resource` object for a given path:

```
<sly data-sly-use.test="/content/core-components-examples"></sly>
<ul data-sly-list="${test.listChildren}">
    <li>${item.path}</li>
</ul>
```